# How to find 32 bit floating point representation of base 10 number?

Tags: floating-point

I had this question on a quiz today. Can anyone explain to me the solution and how to even find the solution?
What is the 32-bit floating point representation of the base-10 number 0.53125? In the options below, the leftmost bit is the most significant bit in the data value.

Comment: You should do some googling of IEEE FP representation, take some numerical-methods maths classes and do some work.

Comment: What do you mean by "the" representation? You mean IEEE-754 binary32? If so, why not read [the spec](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/mostRecentIssue.jsp?punumber=4610933), or a simplified explanation like [Wikipedia's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)? If not, what _do_ you mean?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about doing hard and boring work for someone else's assignment.

Comment: How is the "integer" tag relevant here? Is there more to the question than you've asked?

Answer (score 0):

Here we can show how to convert a base 10 real number into an IEEE 754 binary32 format using the following outline:

consider a real number with an integer and a fraction part such as 12.375
convert and normalize the integer part into binary
convert the fraction part using the following technique as shown here
add the two results and adjust them to produce a proper final conversion

Conversion of the fractional part:

consider 0.375, the fractional part of 12.375. To convert it into a binary fraction, multiply the fraction by 2, take the integer part and re-multiply new fraction by 2 until a fraction of zero is found or until the precision limit is reached which is 23 fraction digits for IEEE 754 binary32 format.

0.375 x 2 = 0.750 = 0 + 0.750 => b−1 = 0, the integer part represents the binary fraction digit. Re-multiply 0.750 by 2 to proceed

0.750 x 2 = 1.500 = 1 + 0.500 => b−2 = 1

0.500 x 2 = 1.000 = 1 + 0.000 => b−3 = 1, fraction = 0.000, terminate

We see that (0.375)10 can be exactly represented in binary as (0.011)2. Not all decimal fractions can be represented in a finite digit binary fraction. For example decimal 0.1 cannot be represented in binary exactly. So it is only approximated.

Therefore (12.375)10 = (12)10 + (0.375)10 = (1100)2 + (0.011)2 = (1100.011)2

Comment: That result isn't IEEE format, it's some kind of fixed-point format where the exponent is always 0 and there's room at least 4 digits left of the point and 3 right of the point. (If you just changed the first sentence, this would be accurate, and a good way to get the asker started on solving his problem.)